# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference1.StockData[] ' to Systems.Collections.Generic.List<StockData>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I'm trying to consume a WCF service that returns a custom list in the form `List<StockData>`.

Here's the method signature from `IService.cs`:

```
 [OperationContract]
     List<StockData> orderStockData(string compName1, string compName2, string compName3);
```

But when I try referencing it in my website through a service reference:

```
List<StockData> list = new List<StockData>();
list = myProxy.orderStockData(txtinput1.Text, txtinput2.Text, txtinput3.Text);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference1.StockData[] ' to Systems.Collections.Generic.List

Any help with solving this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating a `new List<>`, just to assign a different result to that reference?  Just do `var list = myProxy....`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, that gets rid of the error, but I'm not being able to access the elements of list later!

Comment: Why not?  What's not working?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Ive placed both the code of both the service implementation and the proxy. The proxy now throws an index out of bounds error Iservice.cs :https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5219192
Aspx.cs: https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5219195

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you added the reference to your site then under `DataType` ==> `Collection Type` you specified `System.Array`, *(which is default as well)*, that is why your proxy is returning you an array instead of list.

[image]

When adding reference to the web service go to advance and specify `System.Collection.Generic.List` and you will get the same return type as in your contract.

But if you don't want to do that you can still use the Array and convert it to List using `ToList`

**EDIT:**

Like:

```
List<StockData> list = new List<StockData>();
list=(myProxy.orderStockData(txtinput1.Text, txtinput2.Text, txtinput3.Text)).ToList();
```

Comment: How exactly do you pull up this screen? As in from where can I access it

Comment: How did you add the Service References ??usually, right click on the Service References under project in Visual studio, Add service reference, there you will find a button `Advanced`, from there you can find that screen. You can even click on your existing service reference and click update, see if you find the advanced button there.

Comment: @KodeSeeker, you can also check the edited part of the answer, where you can convert the array to List

Comment: @Habib- I tried the converting array to list part but it throws an error saying - `Cannot implicilty convert type Systems.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceReference1.StockData> to Systems.Collections.Generic.List<StockData> `

Comment: Also when I click update, it automatically downloads the service information once again ,there is no `update` option.

Comment: @KodeSeeker, that is because the proxy generated its own class, Try if you can get to the above screen, there is an option to reuse types in all assembillies, check that as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26689/discussion-between-habib-and-kodeseeker)

Comment: @KodeSeeker, remove the reference and try adding it again

Comment: I tried setting the return type to System.Collection.Generic.List in the advanced settings but I get this error again `Cannot implicilty convert type Systems.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceReference1.StockData> to Systems.Collections.Generic.List<StockData> `

Comment: @KodeSeeker, check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286775/wcf-common-types-not-reused

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IList<StockData>`, since `StockData[]` implements this interface it should make everything work.

Also, you don't need to call `new List<T>()` as you are immediately overwriting it with another value.

Comment: `  IList<StockData> list;
 list=myProxy.orderStockData(txtinput1.Text, txtinput2.Text, txtinput3.Text);` Doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

You can change in the service reference settings if you want the proxy to use `List<T>` or `T[]`.

To change the settings, right click the service reference in the project in solution explorer. Pick `"Configure Service Reference"`. In `"Collection type"` pick `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this post and I too faced similar error before but none of the above answers solved the issue.

What *did* work for me is using `var` like below

```
//List<StockData> list = new List<StockData>(); // no need of this

var list=myProxy.orderStockData(txtinput1.Text, txtinput2.Text, txtinput3.Text).Tolist();
```