# Cannot implicitly convert type '.Company[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HRPayRoll.Entities.Company>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf-data-services

Good Day All,

I'm getting the subject exception while getting the list from the service. What I need to do is call the service and that service will return a list of company.

I have the same Entity class on client side application. Now when I try to save the service response into that list I'm getting the subject exception.

**Code Snippet**

```
 private List<Company> companyList = new List<Company>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            SignupServiceRef.SignUPClient signupServ = new SignupServiceRef.SignUPClient();


            companyList = signupServ.processCompanyCategories(); // Here I'm getting the exception
            foreach(Company companyCategory in companyList)
            {
                control_coyCategory.Items.Add(companyList.); // unable to access the variables
            }
            control_userName.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "javascript:checkUserNameExists()");
        }

    }
```

**Enitity**

```
 public class Company
{
    private int _companyId;
    private string _companyName;
    private string _companyAddress;
    private int _companyCategoryId;


    public int companyId
    {
        get { return _companyId; }
        set { _companyId = value; }
    }
    public string companyName
    {
        get { return _companyName; }
        set { _companyName = value; }
    }
    public string companyAddress
    {
        get { return _companyAddress; }
        set { _companyAddress = value; }
    }
    public int companyCategoryId
    {
        get { return _companyCategoryId; }
        set { _companyCategoryId = value; }
    }
}
```

**Service Method**

```
  public List<Company> processCompanyCategories() {

        return coyCategory.getCompanyCategoryList();
    }

  public List<Company> getCompanyCategoryList() {

        return companyManagementDAL.getCompaniesList();
    }

    public List<Company> getCompaniesList()
    {
        List<Company> companyList = companyList = new List<Company>(); ;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.DBConnectionString))
        {

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.SPROC_COMPANY_ALLCOMPANYNAMES, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Company company = new Company();
                company.companyId = (int)reader[0];
                company.companyName = (string)reader[1];
                company.companyAddress = (string)reader[2];
                company.companyCategoryId = (int)reader[3];

                companyList.Add(company);
            }


        }
        return companyList;
    }
```

Comment: signupServ.processCompanyCategories().ToList()

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni I'm not getting, If you look into the code then my service is return a list not an array. But when I try to call thru client application then it converts to an array.

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni I'm getting this exception on compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

The 1st exception:

Collections are exposed as array in Service metadata. Generic lists from a WCF service method will be returned as arrays (by default), please check the client proxy class of this service for the return type of the method.

so we need to do some extra steps to get List on client-side.
Please refer to this post and make the change towards the service reference.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15563298/5080526

The 2nd issue:

It's a good practice to let service return a list via the interface if the client just want to iterate, read and get data; but we could not just only change the return type from `List<Company>` to `IList<Company>` here on the service-side code, because we could not add an array element to a generic List on the client side. So, I am also agree with Ergwun's solution above to solve the issue.